# Firebase with Cordova: which platform to choose

Tags: android, ios, firebase, cordova, web

I'm going to design my first mobile app for both Android and iOS using **Cordova**.
Also, I've decided to heavily rely on **Firebase** as a database and analytics core.

As you may know, Firebase suggests you create the project in one of three platforms: Android, iOS and Web.. and so, I don't know which to choose as I want to create for both mobile platforms using actual **Web** technologies.

On the one hand, it has to be *web-focused* but at the same time, I don't want to miss any *device-oriented* features.

If I create two separate projects for two different platforms, does it mean that there're going to be two different databases/hostings/storages as well?

Answer (score 2):

Same case as React Native apps and Flutter (I suppose) **you will need to manage this separately for both of your applications,**

Simply follow the steps mentioned on the tutorials from Google to enable and connect your app to firebase. Is very easy and I think you are on a good track.

Hope this helps

Comment: do you think this tutorial fits the described above purpose?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

Answer (score 1):

You need to create for Android AND iOS if you plan on using the Firebase plugin for cordova, as the plugin relies on the native layer and not the web layer in cordova.

You will only need google-services.json for android and GoogleService-Info.plist for ios if you use the plugin. These config files will be available once you create the android and ios projects in firebase.

Comment: how about config files and sdk that firebase provides to download? aren't they created for native environments? should I just ignore them?

Comment: see my edit about config files